# KnockoutJS binding with default class when the property for the css binding is null

Tags: javascript, knockout-3.0

I'm working on an existing project and I'm still learning KnockoutJS so maybe I won't be able to provide full description, but the case is this.

I have a `<div>` element which looks like this:

```
'<div data-bind="text: CSS || \'Default text\', css: CSS || \'default-css\'" class="some-classes"></div>'
```

**What I want**
When the `CSS` property is `Null` to apply the `css` binding with the default class for this case. And since the use case is such, later on I want to be able to change the binded `css` property to some other value.

**What happens**

I have this function which handles the event when I need to rebind the `<div>`

```
function RebindDiv(data, event) {
  var element = $(event.currentTarget).parent().prev('.<selector>').get(0);
  ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { text: data.CSS(), css: data.CSS() });

  $(function () { $(element).change() }); //triggers the KO binding
}
```

So when the event is triggered if initially I've binded the `css` in the `<div>` like so : `css: CSS || \'default-css\"` then the `default-css` is not applied when the page is rendered but after I trigger the event the css's are applied successfully. If I remove the `||` check and leave only `css: CSS` and then add the default css like so : `class="default-css, <other classes>"` then when the page is rendered the class is applied (not a big surprise there) but new styles are not applied each time and overall it seems that this is not the correct way.

**Question** 
Is there a way to keep the KO's `css` binding and still use default class if the property is not set at the beginning?

Comment: It's probably that the object you're testing against (`CSS` in this case), is actually an observable hence would never evaluate to `false`. It's the underlying value that is 'falsy'. Try to test against the unwrapped value instead: `css: ko.unwrap(CSS) || 'default-css'`

Comment: Also, if you set your `data-bind` attribute value using double-quotes (`"`), there is no need to escape single-quote literals.

Comment: Usually, there is no need to manually `unwrap` (for example, when merely passing a reference to an observable to some handler: `text: someObservable`). But in your case, you're passing an expression what is evaluated as a whole, hence KO doesn't (or cannot) parse it to find the exact pieces that needs to be unwrapped.

Comment: @haim770 I'll try this but the first part `text: CSS || \'Default text\'` is working so I doubt that this is the issue. I'm currently looking at knockout documentation `data-bind="css: { profitWarning: currentProfit() < 0 }"` but can't quite think of a way how to get use of this example.

Comment: Well, if you know `CSS` is observable then you really should invoke it when evaluating its value: `text: CSS() || 'Default Text'`.